Fetching entity property as a collection using jpa criteria and metamodel
I have entities like:
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@TypeDef(name = "uuid-char", typeClass = UUIDCharType.class)
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true)
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID uuid;

    @NonNull
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    @Builder.Default
    @OneToMany
    private Collection<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

    //other fields

}

And the Post entity:
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @NonNull
    private String status;

    @Getter
    @Nullable
    private OffsetDateTime published;


}

I am trying to fetch projections of user entities containing list of posts.
The class for projection is
public record UserResponse(UUID uuid, Collection posts){}
So I am using criteria api.
 CriteriaQuery<UserResponse> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(UserResponse.class);
    Root<User> user= query.from(User.class);

    Join<User, Post> posts = user.join(User_.posts);

    user.fetch(User.posts, JoinType.INNER);

    query.multiselect(
            user.get(User_.uuid),
            user.join(User_.posts)
    );

    Expression<OffsetDateTime> atExpression = buldCriteria();
    return query;

Unfortunatelly I am getting not matching constructor exception - it expects single Post object and not a collection. How to use those projections together with criteria API so I can select object with field being a collection?
